# Avoid S-Trap Sink Plumbing

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

Any suggestions how I avoid an S-Trap when installing my bathroom sink when the drain rough-in is installed coming up through the floor (foundation)? See image below - sink hookup is on the right.

[image]

Comment: Have you [found your vents](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/213202/plumbing-basement-bathroom) yet? That's key information. You're getting ahead of yourself.

Comment: And you should follow up on the other question you posted. We're waiting for some clarification over there that could help.

Comment: Install the vent pipes, and install a P trap.

Answer (score -2):

Since you framed the wall behind the in-concrete drain rough-in, you will use an S-trap from the bowl to the drain on the floor. Had you really wanted to use a P-trap, you would have framed the wall directly over the rough-in, used a P-trap into the wall, then an elbow down to the rough-in in the floor.

If you *really* want to use a P-trap then you'll need to move your wall. Since that does seem quite rather impractical (and probably makes the toilet rough-in unusably close to the wall), just stick with the S-trap. Functionally, an S- & P-trap work the same. I'm not aware of any additional clogging issues with an S-trap over a P (I have all S in my house and have very minimal clogging issues, especially since the long-haired daughter moved out on her own), so there's nothing to worry about there.

<s>Dropping</s> Placing a vanity over the pipe in the floor really isn't that difficult in comparison to pushing it up against the wall. You have to measure carefully in each case to get the hole cut (in the floor or the back, as appropriate) in the proper place, but you just make the hole a bit oversized and it's not difficult in either case. There's no requirement that the pipe be perfectly centered for either installation method.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true. There may be a vent stub above that could be used. Also, s-traps are not allowed.

Comment: S-traps are not allowed? News to me - since when? Why are they still sold in stores? (existing installs, I know...)

Comment: There are many discussions on it here. They tend to siphon dry.

Comment: I never realized the siphoning only happened to S-traps and that they were subsequently banned for it.

Answer (score -3):

You're in luck. I just handled this myself. Swapped an old leaking s-trap for all solvent joints and a standard 1-½” trap with a compression fitting that slides onto the tail of the sink drain. I was forced to re-do everything from my cast iron up to the vanity and I needed to install a mini vent, hence why I kept it all at 1-½”. I’ll see if I can grab a picture for you. Since your wall is opened up though, I would really look into seeing if you can plumb it in the wall and stub it out like normal. Lifting a vanity and setting it down onto your plumbing is a PITA.

Comment: I don't see an answer here. Be aware that we're not a discussion forum. Please take the [tour].